# Wait in Mocha api tests

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, mocha.js, supertest

I have following api test written in Mocha
I put inserts to database and edited values are available in api response after 5 min (cache).

How i should wait for cache in my test caseses?
Now i using following code, and it gives me error

```
     Error: Timeout of 30000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (C:\apiTests\test\07_0_dbtests.js)
```

My function:

```
    it('should get updated restaurant calendar for dine in', function (done) {
  this.timeout(30000);
  setTimeout(function(){
  tempUrl = `/rest/v1/restaurants/${config.restaurant_id_for_sql_queries}/DINE_IN`;
  request
    .get(tempUrl)
    .set(config.headers)
    .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${auth_token}`)
    .end(function (err, res) {
      logger.info(utils.logToConsole(res.request.url));
      assert.equal(res.status, 200, 'response status!=200');
      today = utils.getDayNameFromDate(utils.getTodayDate());
      jsonstring = "";
      switch (new Date().getDay()) {
        case 0: assert.isTrue(res.body.details.channels.DINE_IN.openHoursSun.closeAllDay, 'restaurant should be closed all day'); break;
        case 1: assert.isTrue(res.body.details.channels.DINE_IN.openHoursMon.closeAllDay, 'restaurant should be closed all day'); break;
        case 2: assert.isTrue(res.body.details.channels.DINE_IN.openHoursTue.closeAllDay, 'restaurant should be closed all day'); break;
        case 3: assert.isTrue(res.body.details.channels.DINE_IN.openHoursWed.closeAllDay, 'restaurant should be closed all day'); break;
        case 4: assert.isTrue(res.body.details.channels.DINE_IN.openHoursThu.closeAllDay, 'restaurant should be closed all day'); break;
        case 5: assert.isTrue(res.body.details.channels.DINE_IN.openHoursFri.closeAllDay, 'restaurant should be closed all day'); break;
        case 6: assert.isTrue(res.body.details.channels.DINE_IN.openHoursSat.closeAllDay, 'restaurant should be closed all day'); break;
      }
      assert.isTrue(res.body.details.channels.DINE_IN.closeAllDay, 'restaurant should be closed all day');
      done(err);
    });
  },30000);
});
```

Do you have experience in waiting? How i can do it properly?

Comment: Have you tried anything to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
this.timeout(30000);
```

so it will wait 30s.

You can use:

```
this.timeout(360000); // '6m'
```

to increase the timeout to 6 mins(you can change 360000 to other value).

Comment: i know how to change timeout, but problem is that test case gives me error posted above after 30 second instead of positive assertion

Comment: You change timeout 6 min and it throws in 30s, alright?